# How to add and enable rewrite module in manually installed apache httpd web server?

Tags: apache2, kubuntu, mod-rewrite

I installed apache httpd server by compiling source on Kubuntu 14.10.
I ran

```
wget http://www.us.apache.org/dist//httpd/httpd-2.2.29.tar.gz
tar -xzf httpd-2.2.29.tar.gz
cd httpd-2.2.29
./configure --enable-shared=max
make
sudo make install
```

I followed [these steps](http://www.mkyong.com/apache/how-to-install-apache-http-server-in-ubuntu/)

I am able to run and stop the server
`sudo /usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl -k start`  to start server
`sudo /usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl -k stop`  to stop server

I am able to see loaded modules also

```
/usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -M
```

In the list of loaded modules there is no mod_rewrite so I want to add and enable it. How can I enable that module in a manually installed httpd server?

Answer (score 2):

After seeing [this official documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/install.html) I am able to add and enable rewrite module.

```
wget http://www.us.apache.org/dist//httpd/httpd-2.2.29.tar.gz
tar -xzf httpd-2.2.29.tar.gz
cd httpd-2.2.29
./configure --enable-rewrite=shared
make
sudo make install
```